# Adding an id to the output of some php

Tags: php, html, wordpress

i have a small code,

i need to add a class to the output

```
$output_html .= ' ' . groovy_menu_woocommerce_mini_cart_counter( $qty ) . ' ';
```

which output a

```
<span class="gm-cart-counter">2</span>
```

how to add an id to the output of

```
' . groovy_menu_woocommerce_mini_cart_counter( $qty ) . '
```

so it look like this

```
<span id="newid"class="gm-cart-counter">2</span>
```

new code tested

```
$span = groovy_menu_woocommerce_mini_cart_counter($qty);
$spanWithId = "<span id='the-id'" ;
```

that work and show a span with the-id id

but this doesnt

```
$span = groovy_menu_woocommerce_mini_cart_counter($qty);
$spanWithId = "<span id='the-id'"  . $span;
```

Comment: you need to find and edit groovy_menu_woocommerce_mini_cart_counter() function It's wordpress related problem , so maybe you should ask in https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

This is ugly but it should do the trick:

```
$span = groovy_menu_woocommerce_mini_cart_counter($qty);
$spanWithId = "<span id='the-id'" . substr($span, 5, strlen($span));
$output_html .= $spanWithId;

echo "$spanWithId";
```

**Output:**

```
<span id='the-id' class="gm-cart-counter">2</span>
```

**Try this**

```
    global $woocommerce;

    $qty = 0;
    if ($tks == true) {
        $qty = $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_contents_count();
    }

    $cartIcon = 'fa fa-shopping-cart';

    $span = groovy_menu_woocommerce_mini_cart_counter($qty);
    $spanWithId = "<span id='the-id'" . substr($span, 5, strlen($span));

    $output_html .= '
                <div class="gm-minicart minicartmarie">
                    <a href="' . get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'cart' ) ) . '" class="gm-minicart-link minicartmarie">
                        <div class="gm-badge">
                            <i class="gm-icon ' . esc_attr( $cartIcon ) . '"></i>
                            ' . $spanWithId . '
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                ';
```

You correctly replaced the call to `groovy_menu_woocommerce_mini_cart_counter($qty)` but you included a `;` in the statement which breaks it.

Also, instead of `echo`ing `$spanWithId` you should `echo $output_html`

Comment: i need to apply the code to this doh,   $output_html .= ' ' . groovy_menu_woocommerce_mini_cart_counter( $qty ) . ' ';

Comment: @Agustin - Just change the variable names ... I added the extra line.

Comment: ok i do believe that would work but i am too newb, let me show you the full code, i will edit the upper post

Comment: Take a look now. It didn't work because the way you added it was wrong.

Comment: now i dont get error but the ouput still come out without id, i will put the code tested and the output in the upper post

Comment: Does `groovy_menu_woocommerce_mini_cart_counter()` echo or return a value? Also, are you certain these changes are running?

Comment: yes its a localhost site, so as soon as saved everything is applied, but i dont know what the counter does, if it return or echo, :/ sorry i can find my way around python but im a 0 in php

Comment: change `$output_html .= '` to `$output_html .= ' TEST` and rerun it. Make sure that TEST appears before the `<div>` tag.

Comment: Remove TEST and before the `$output_html .= '` statement, add `echo "span - $span\n spanWithId - $spanWithId\n";` That should print out the two spans.

Comment: nothing, i will put the code tested and output up there

Comment: Remove that new `echo` line. Change `$output_html .= '`line to `$output_html .= 'span - $span <br /> spanWithId - $spanWithId <br />'`

Comment: Try the other answer out, it's cleaner.

Comment: mm i probably did it wrong it gives me an error, d the code and output up there

Comment: no i couldnt manage to do it, im pretty sure your coding is right, but there must be something i have been missing

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I would do.

```
// create a wrapper function that injects the id
function menu_with_id($qty, $id){
  $span = groovy_menu_woocommerce_mini_cart_counter($qty);
  return str_replace('<span', "<span id='$id'", $span);
}

// then replace it
$output_html .= ' ' . menu_with_id($qty, $id) . ' ';
```